# C - linked list cannot convert node** to node*

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I was studying linked lists and copying my examiners notes exactly and couldn't get it to work. The error says that I

> cannot convert 'node**' to node*'.

I have tried changing the types so that they match but that just causes it to crash once I run it. If someone could give me some insight into why this is happening it would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
}*head;

main(){
    int i;

    node *n1, *n2, *temp;

    temp = n1;

    n1->number = 1;
    n1->next = &n2;

    n2->number = 2;
    n2->next = NULL;



   return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
n1->next = &n2;
```

change to

```
n1->next = n2;
```

Reason behind this is, the types of the variables involved. `n1->next` is of type `struct node *`, so as `n2`. `&n2` will be of type `struct node **`

However, still this instruction will be erroneous [and your program / code snippet produces [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)], since  `n1` and `n2` are both unitialized till this point. <sup>NOTE</sup>

- Allocate memory for `n1`, `n2` using `malloc()` [or family]
- Atleast consider initializing `n1`,`n2`, `temp` to `NULL`[and all other local variables also, for that matter].

*Note: Related readings,*

- For read-before-write in `temp = n1;` and for using uninialized memory `n1->number`

From chapter 6.7.8, paragraph 10, `C99` standard

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

and , `Annex J` of the same document, from `J.2`

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate

Comment: Doing that runs the program but it immediately crashes.

Comment: @Ironicism doing what? in case you need to run this whole code, you need to allocate memory for `n1` and `n2` both, at very least. What's the use of `temp` here?

Comment: @Ironicism Also, I'd suggest, learn to use a debugger , like `gdb`. It help immensly while debugging.

Comment: Thank you. We haven't really gone into malloc/calloc soI was unaware I needed to do that but it worked wonderfully. Also I agree a debugger is definitely something I need to learn to use.

Comment: @Ironicism You're welcome . I've edited my answer to add a bit more explanation :-) BTW, you can consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) an answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The major problem lies with the statement:

```
n1->next = &n2;
```

Here, `n->next` is of type `node*` (see the definition of struct node, you will find that it has a member `next` has type `struct node*`), whereas, you are assigning `&n2` to it, which is a pointer to `n2`. `n2` itself is a pointer variable to the type `struct node`, therefore, `&n2` is a pointer to a pointer to `struct node` type.

This leads to a type mismatch and hence, the error.

Other issues would be that `n2` is not initialized when assigning it to `n1->next`, `n1` is not initialized when assigning it to `temp`.